# MAMP showing an older version of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, mamp

My macbook shut down unexpected. After starting it again, when going to localhost, I can see an older version of my wordpress website. Looks like the database rolled back. Is there anything I can do ? If not I am loosing most of my work.

I tought it's the cache but I've tried everything that I know to clean the cache and I don't think this is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally use MAMP for MAC, the free version. For some reasons, way back I played with MAMP PRO and it's install on my machine. Now I've just launched MAMP PRO and restarted the servers and BOOOOM! It worked. I can now see my recent changes in my Wordpress website.

I'm still confused why this had happed ? I've searched on google but nothing similar with my problem.

Comment: MAMP and MAMP PRO do not use the same databases. When MAMP PRO is started for the first time, the contents of the database are copied from MAMP to MAMP PRO. For this reason, the contents you created in MAMP PRO were not visible in MAMP.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying that.